# -bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory when trying to run a flask app in localhost

Tags: python, python-venv

I had a project I didn't started for a while, and now that I'm trying to initiate it I'm getting this error:

```
-bash: /Users/ntactBook/venv/bin/pip: /Users/ntactBook/venv/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How did I encounter this error? First:

In order to activate my venv, I did:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then, the venv gets activated normally.

So the I do `python app.py` to run the app in localhost but I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'`  As if I had no libraries installed in my venv.

So I do `pip install boto3`, but it throws me this bash error. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It's mentioned in the second line

Comment: What are the contents of `/Users/nicolasrizzoehrenbock/Documents/ContactBook/venv/bin/`?

Comment: There are a lot of files, mainly .py ones

Comment: Specifically, does it have any executable files named `python`, or `python2`, or `python3`?